# Get parent from HTML string

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table row that is dynamically created, so I have no control to add any ids or classes.
The row can appear in any order in the table.  Each row contains only on column (td).

**UPDATED 31/08/2012 18:55**

Here is a sample of how the html might look

```
<table id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <p>
         <span style="font-size:1.1em"><span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList_ctl00_lblCourseInfoTypeText" style="font-weight:bold;">Subject Area</span></span>
         <br />
         <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList_ctl00_lblCourseInfoText">BS, AP</span>
         </p>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <p>
         <span style="font-size:1.1em"><span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList_ctl01_lblCourseInfoTypeText" style="font-weight:bold;">Course Content</span></span>
         <br />
         <span id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList_ctl01_lblCourseInfoText">some more text</span>
         </p>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way that I can hide the row where 'Subject Area' appears?

Comment: What is the pattern for the `id`? It always starts with `ctl00_Main...`?

Comment: `$('#ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList_ctl00_lblCourseInfoTypeText').parent().hide();` ? I bet there's a better way to solve this though, but it's hard to suggest anything without more context information.

Comment: please elaborate I can't understand?

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for you replies.  I've added some example html and a bit more explanation. The key thing is the 'bad' row could appear anywhere with any number e.g. ct100, ct108 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think I can answer my own question :S

```
$("#ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList tr:contains('Subject Area')").hide();
```

This is a bit more selective and less likely to catch any other instances of 'Subject Area' that we actually want.

```
$("#ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList span:contains('Subject Area')").closest('tr').hide();
```

Discovering the contains function was key here, so thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.closest('tr')`, it will grab the next `<tr>` tag up the DOM tree:

```
$('#ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_ctl00_CourseInfoTextList_ctl00_lblCourseInfoTypeText').closest('tr').hide();
```

Instead of `.hide()`, you could use `.slideUp()`, `.fadeOut()` or `.remove()` etc

Comment: Hi.  Sorry for the late reply.  I've added some example html and a bit more explanation. The key thing is the 'bad' row could appear anywhere with any number e.g. ct100, ct108 etc

Answer (score 0):

Dunhamzzz is right, closest works great (+1).

On a side note, ASP.NET webforms makes absolutely absurdly long dynamic ID names, and Ithe idea of putting in `<%= Whatever.ClientID %>` inside of your JS (mixing back-end & front-end) is ridiculous to me.

Just use the *from the end* selector instead, to keep your JS clean.

```
$('[id$="lblCourseInfoTypeText"]').closest('tr').hide();
// ^= means search from the end - and voila
```

Comment: From the end is a dollar sign `[id$="value"]` :)

Comment: Crap - brain fart :) Still too early haha. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Hi.  Sorry for taking so long to reply.  I've tried that one my page but it hides all tr's.  I wasn't very clear in my original post, so I've added a bit more detail better example html.  As far as I can see, the only unique value that we know and wont change is 'Subject Area'.  Not sure if there is a way to target that?  I'm still learning all the JQuery functions LOL